# Как отобразить сепаратор под иконкой в ContextMenu?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Есть два MenuItem'a между ними сепаратор, но как его отобразить под иконкой?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

MenuItem xaml

```
<Button Content="Right-click me!" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Button.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Menu item 1" />
                <MenuItem Header="Menu item 2" />
                <Separator />
                <MenuItem Header="Menu item 3" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </Button.ContextMenu>
    </Button>
```

Comment: А как вы отображаете иконку? Покажите свой XAML.

Comment: @Bulson добавил в вопрос

Comment: @AdamHodovanets, а можно минимальный самодостаточный пример, такой чтобы вставить в студию и запустить, но в то же время, чтоб ничего лишнего?

Comment: @АндрейNOP да вообщем то простое контекстное меню, там сепаратор прорисовывается уже после иконок

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стандартный шаблон сепаратора имеет вид:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
    <Grid Margin="0,6,0,4" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" UseLayoutRounding="False">
        <Rectangle Fill="#E0E0E0" Height="1" Margin="30,0,1,1"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="White" Height="1" Margin="30,1,1,0"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Как видно, в нем сделан отступ с помощью `Margin`, просто исправьте это:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="MySeparatorTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
        <Grid Margin="0,6,0,4" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" UseLayoutRounding="False">
            <Rectangle Fill="#E0E0E0" Height="1" Margin="1,0,1,1"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="White" Height="1" Margin="1,1,1,0"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Button Content="Right-click me!" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Menu item 1" />
            <MenuItem Header="Menu item 2" />
            <Separator Template="{StaticResource MySeparatorTemplate}"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Menu item 3" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]